# Finding a good word for company-internal open source

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

*Open source* is normally associated with making code available to the public.

I am looking to express another concept and (wrongly) associate it with open source.

Imagine a large distributed organization of competing units. These units develop and possess proprietary code.

Some of them decide to "open source" this code internally, that is, make it available to all members.

What is the proper term which is not misleading? *Internal open source*?

Comment: There is something like "semi-open source" (google for it). As far as I get it, it either restricts the free access to a specific part of the code or to a specific group of people e.g. scientists. If you consider "the organization" as a group of people, "semi-open source" could work here. Anyway, if using "semi-open source" one always has to define what "semi" means exactly. My semi-open source doesn't have to be the same as yours. By the way, there is nothing odd about "internal open source".

Comment: What about '*shared source*' or '*source sharing*'?

Comment: This question belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Super User.

Comment: @HotLicks Please see https://superuser.com/help/on-topic This question would not be on topic there.

Comment: @CJDennis - More on-topic there than here.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not saying it's on topic here (nor am I saying that it's off topic here), just that moving it to a site where it's off topic is unhelpful.

Comment: @Smock - How about *Company Shared Source*?

Comment: @Jim - makes no odds to me - ask OP!

Comment: @Jim How about *code that is looking for a team to take ownership of it*?

Comment: @jxh - Seems like until someone steps up it’s: Company Abandoned Source.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Internal open source" is OK. Or "InnerSource" can be used.
https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/10/innersource-at-paypal/